# Why are we multiplying Area of P in the statement "Area of L(P) = |Det L| (Area of P)"?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

In *Introduction to Linear Algebra* (2nd edition), Lang gives [a proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVQgZ.jpg) of the statement

$$\text{Area of $L(P)$} = |\det L| (\text{Area of $P$}).$$

I don't understand he multiplies by "Area of $P$" in this statement.

Why do we need to multiply Area of $P$ on the right-hand side while going from the statement
$$\text{Area of $P$} = \lvert\det L\rvert$$ to $$\text{Area of $L(P)$} = \lvert \det L\rvert (\text{Area of $P$})?$$

Please explain in simple terms as I am not very experienced with linear algebra.

Comment: The linear transformation $L$ changes all areas proportionally - that is, by the same factor, which happens to be $\det L$.

Comment: I get it. When Lang mentions Area of P = |Det L|, the area of the unit square (which is equal to one) is scaled by the determinant of L. But how did he conclude that Area of P = |Det L|?

Comment: He is interpreting theorem 6.1, which means the assertion was probably proved in theorem 6.1.

Comment: @Kakashi Thanks. He did conclude "Area of P = |Del L|" using Theorem 6.1 which states "The area of the parallelogram spanned by v, w is equal to the absolute value of the determinant, namely |D(v, w)|."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's using the letter $P$ in two different ways. If you read carefully, the argument where he proves that the area of $P$ is $\lvert\det L\rvert$ is based on taking the particular case where $P=L(C)$, where $C$ is the unit square. The other use of $P$ is quite general.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the clear explanation of @TedShifrin's answer using the notion of scaling given by @EthanBolker.

In the statement
$$\text{Area of $P$} = \lvert\operatorname{Det}L\rvert,$$
the area of C (which is a unit square, so it has area equal to 1) is scaled to the area of P using the Det L factor.

And in the other statement
$$\text{Area of $L(P)$} = \lvert \operatorname{Det} L\rvert (\text{Area of $P$})$$
the area of P is scaled to the area of L(P) using the Det L factor.

(L in the two statements is not the same because they have different associated matrices.)

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, and from your answer I derived this explanation. But your answer is hard to understand so I wrote this "relatively easy to understand" answer.